# Change Text Size on PullToRefreshLIst?

Tags: java, android, text, size

yesterday, I used the component call PullToRefreshList from 
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh and installed it into my project.

It works, but I think the text size is too big. How can I shrink the font size?

Answer (score 1):

The layout file `pull_to_refresh_header.xml` in **layout** folder contains views shown while pulling down the list. Modify the attributes in this file to change the look of its views

for example:

```
android:textSize="12dp"
```

Comment: Im sorry, but its doesnt work.
I want to shrink the list text not the header text (refresh).
Is it possible ?

Comment: yes, you may do it simply by creating your own customized Adapter. Read this for more details http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter